# Why Flutter Firebase Messaging on Message not working always?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, localnotification, flutter-notification

I'm using Flutter Firebase Messaging with Flutter Local Notification I followed all steps in the document example, I have a problem which is: the OnMessage listener has not fired always, sometimes I got Message BroadCast Received but on Message function not being invoked? How can I fix it?

I'm trying to keep the firebase messaging always working when the app is opened

Comment: call it from your init function at your main.dart